# D3 getting the id of polygon underneath while dragging a circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a d3 object, its made up of triangular polygons.

I have a draggable circle pointer  how do I  capture the id of the polygon underneath the mouse( under the mouse event, while the circle is still behaving like a visual pointer). Hope that makes sense.

Html

```
  <div style="width:1000px;" id="triangle">
    <svg height="1000" width="1000" id="ternary">  
        <defs>
            <!--The Pointe-->
            <g id="pointer" transform="scale(0.8)">
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>     
            </g>
        </defs>
         </svg>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {

        var ternary = d3.select("#ternary");
        var pointer = d3.select("#pointer");
        var w = 50,
            h = 50,
            rows = 20;
        b = 1000;
        t = 950;
        wm = 25;
        var osb = 0;

        for (s = 1; s <= 20; s++) {

            if (!s % 2 == 0) {
                rb = b - osb;
                rt = t - osb;

            } else {
                rb = b - osb;
                rt = t - osb;

            }
            for (i = 1; i <= rows - s; i++) {
                console.log();
                osl = (i - 1) * w + ((s - 1) * 25);
                if (s) {
                    if (s % 2 == 0) {
                        trColor = '#3c763d';
                        osl = (i - 1) * w + ((s - 1) * 25);
                        var x1 = osl;
                        var x2 = osl + (w / 2);;
                        var x3 = osl + w;
                        // console.log(rt);
                        ternary.append('polygon')
                            .attr('points', osl + ' ' + (rt) + ',  ' + x3 + ' ' + (rt) + ' , ' + x2 + ' ' + (rb))
                            .attr('class', 'r' + s + 'c' + i)
                            .style('fill', '#3c754d');
                    } else {
                        trColor = '#3c739d'
                        osl = (i - 1) * w + ((s - 1) * 25);
                        var x1 = osl;
                        var x2 = osl + (w / 2);;
                        var x3 = osl + w;

                        ternary.append('polygon')
                            .attr('points', osl + ' ' + rb + ',  ' + x2 + ' ' + rt + ' , ' + x3 + ' ' + rb)
                            .attr('class', 'r' + s + 'c' + i)
                            .style('fill', '#3c763d');

                    };

                }
            }

            if (s % 2 == 0 && s > 2) {

                osb = osb + 50;
            }
        }




        ternary.append("use")
            .attr("href", "#pointer")
            .attr("x", 500)
            .attr("y", 875)
            .attr("fill", "#039BE5")
            .attr("stroke", "#039BE5")
            .attr("stroke-width", "1px");


        var dragHandler = d3.drag()
            .on("drag", function() {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr("x", d3.event.x)
                    .attr("y", d3.event.y);
                /*
                  How do I Get the id of underlying triangle?
                */

            });

        dragHandler(svg.selectAll("use"));
    });
```

Is their a straightforward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for this to find what is under the dragged element.

One is to take advantage of the `start` and `end` events of the drag to change the dragged object's pointer events property as needed. On drag start we can set it to `none`, on drag end, we can restore pointer events to `all`. The drag continues despite setting pointer events to none, but now pointer events can now fire for what is underneath the dragged element.

We can also use the start/end events to add event listeners to the underlying elements, if we only want them to respond to drag events.

The below snippet uses this idea, drag the circle to interact with the underlying rects. When the drag starts, pointer events are removed from the circle and mouse event listeners are added to the rects. At the end of the drag, everything is set back to how it was:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",500)
  .attr("height",300);
  
function color(d) {
  return d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["teal","steelblue","crimson","orange"])
    .domain([0,30,40,60])(d);
}
  
var grid = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(60))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return Math.floor(d/10)*50; })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d%10*50; })
  .attr("fill", color)
  .attr("id", function(d){
    return "rect-"+d;
  })

  
var circle  = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 100)
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", 10);
  
var drag = d3.drag()
  .on("start",start)
  .on("drag",dragged)
  .on("end",end);
  
circle.call(drag);

function start() {
  grid.on("mouseover", function() {
    d3.select(this).attr("fill","yellow");
    console.log(this.id);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    d3.select(this).attr("fill",color);
  })
  
  d3.select(this)
    .style("pointer-events","none");
}
function dragged() {
  d3.select(this)
    .attr("cx", d3.mouse(this)[0])
    .attr("cy", d3.mouse(this)[1]);
}
function end() {
  grid.on("mouseover",null)
   .on("mouseout", null)
   .transition()
   .attr("fill",color);

  d3.select(this)
    .style("pointer-events","all");
  
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 30px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey almost,my grid is a triangle it allows the pointer to move outside the group containing the triangle

Comment: The shape of the path doesn't change the dynamic, and the circle can be dragged beyond the extent of the other paths/shapes - the principle remains the same: on drag start change pointer events to none on the circle and add an event listener to the shapes you want to get the id from, on drag end, change pointer events back and remove the event listeners on the underlying shapes.

Comment: Thanks I added an in true false variable triggering onleave, and just stop modifying the position when its false

Comment: Is their anyway to move the pointer and start drag on mouse click on the parent grid?

Comment: You could assign the listener to the grid - but use it to move the circle (afterall, just because you call d3.drag on something doesn't mean you need to actually move that element). This might need a bit of tweaking for proper implementation - might be best as posted as a new question so that others can see (they might have better ideas).